# Plot Ellipse based on EigenSystem

Tags: graphics, probability-or-statistics

Please consider the following :

```
covMatrice = {{34.925, -10.21}, {-10.21, 22.462}};

COG = Mean@(Nfixations["d"][[1]])[[All, 1]];

fixations = {{19.4688, 17.4281}, {18.0563, 21.7156}, {13.0219, 24.7219}, 
         {22.9594,25.5219}, {28.5406, 24.6719}, {27.0688, 17.1656}, 
         {27.6781,16.325}, {28.9281, 10.7719}, {16.025, 13.6625}, 
         {19.1313, 17.1094}};


With[{
      eigVec = Eigenvectors[covMatrice],
      eigVal = Eigenvalues[covMatrice]},
      Graphics[{
                White, Rectangle @@ frmXY, 
                Black, Disk[#, .5] & /@ fixations, 
                Red, Line[(# + COG) & /@
                           {eigVec[[1]]*eigVal[[1]]/5, 
                           {0, 0},
                           eigVec[[2]]*eigVal[[2]]/5}]}]]
```

[image]

How could I draw an ellipse representing on the EigenSystem given that Neither Disk or Circle enable to implement an "orientation" ?

A rough example of my desired output as drawn using PPT :

[image]

Comment: The [documentation suggests using rotate](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Disk.html#19774549) to get all possible ellipses. (See the answers below for code!)

Comment: @Simon `Rotate` works fine if you know the angle. As the OP only has the new coordinates, `GeometricTransformation` is the better choice.

Comment: If I may be indulged some numerical advice: it might not always be a good idea to form a covariance matrix from your data for the express purpose of seeing ellipses (or ellipsoids) for that matter. You should look into the singular value decomposition, for instance.

Comment: Just careful, it's the roots of the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix what you want to be using as semi-axis lengths

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Rotate` to draw the ellipse too. Note that knowing the eigenvectors is the same as knowing the orientation of the ellipse, so there is no necessity to favour `GeometricTransformation` over `Rotate`. So, to orient your ellipse along the first eigenvector (corresponding to the largest eigenvalue), it is as simple as:

```
Graphics[Rotate[Disk[meanVec, eigVals], ArcTan @@ eigVecs[[1]]]]
```

[image]

where `meanVec` is the mean (here, I've taken it to be `{0,0}`)

---

Going by your comment under rcollyer's answer, here's a example reproducing your desired figure with simple shifting (change the center of the disk) and rotation of the disk. This approach will be simpler to follow (as the transformations are spelled out), if you do not understand what `GeometricTransformation` does. Modifying rcollyer's module,

```
Module[{mat = #, avg = Mean@fixations, eigVals, eigVecs},
   {eigVals, eigVecs} = Eigensystem@mat;
   Graphics[{{Black, Disk[#, .5] & /@ fixations}, 
      {Directive[Opacity[0.1], Red, EdgeForm[Gray]], 
          Rotate[Disk[avg, eigVals/5], ArcTan @@ eigVecs[[1]]]}
   }]
]&@covMatrice
```

[image]

Comment: I figured I needed to give you an upvote since you clearly answer the question. :P

Answer (score 12):

The simplest approach is to rotate an ellipse aligned with the coordinate axes to axes specified by the eigenvectors. Using your matrix,

```
{evals, evects} = Eigensystem@covMatrice
(*
=> {{40.6549, 16.7321}, {{-0.872057, 0.489405}, {-0.489405, -0.872057}}}
*)

Graphics[ GeometricTransformation[ Disk[{0,0}, evals], evecs\[Transpose] ] ]
```

produces

[image: rotated ellipse]

**Edit**: From the comments, the previous code was incomplete in that the ellipse needed to be centered over the other graphics objects. [`GeometricTransformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GeometricTransformation.html) functions by taking as its second argument a [`TransformationFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TransformationFunction.html) and applying it to the `Graphics` objects passed in via its first argument. An alternate form of `GeometricTransformation` accepts a matrix representing the transformation, instead, and that is what the above code uses. In essence, every point, `r`, in the object is turned into `m.r`, where `m` is the matrix. The third form accepts a matrix and a translation vector, `v`, transforming each point into `m.r + v`.  The following code uses that form to center the ellipse at the mean position of the fixations:

```
Module[{mat = #, avg = Mean@fixations, g, evals, evecs},
  {evals, evecs} = Eigensystem@mat;
  g = GeometricTransformation[#, {evecs\[Transpose], avg}] &;
  Graphics[{
    {Black, Disk[#, .5] & /@ fixations},
    {Directive[Opacity[0.1], Red,  EdgeForm[Gray]], g@Disk[{0, 0}, evals/5]},
    {Red, Line[(# + avg) & /@ Riffle[evecs evals/5, {{0, 0}}] ]}
  }]
] & @ covMatrice
```

which produces

[image: rotated ellipse translated over data points]

I consider this method superior to `Rotate` in that no other calculations are needed.

Comment: thank you it takes the good shape but I can`t place it correctly with my other Graphics objects there is a systematic shift toward the {0,0}. I don`t understand GeometricTransformation and can`t figure out how to adjust the coordinates of the resulting  graphics object.

Comment: @500, I've added the correction. Sorry about that. You wanted to use the third form of `GeometricTransformation` not the second, which is what I was using.

Answer (score 7):

If you know the angle, try using `Rotate`, simple example:

```
Graphics[{Rotate[Disk[{0, 0}, {1, 2}], \[Pi]/4]}]
```

(note: the two argument form of `Rotate` rotates around the center of the primitive)

Here is a more complete example with a `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{
   Lighter[Pink],
   EdgeForm[{AbsoluteThickness[3], Gray}],
   Rotate[Disk[{cx, cy}, {rx, ry}], a, {cx, cy}],
   {Red, Rotate[
     Line[{{cx, cy}, {cx + rx, cy}}], a, {cx, cy}]},
   {Red, Rotate[
     Line[{{cx, cy}, {cx, cy + ry}}], a, {cx, cy}]},
   {Blue, Line[{{0, 0}, {cx, cy}}]}
   }, PlotRange -> 7, Axes -> True, GridLines -> Automatic],
 {{a, 2}, 0, 2 \[Pi]},
 {{rx, 3}, .5, 3},
 {{ry, 1}, .5, 3},
 {{cx, 3}, -3, 3},
 {{cy, 3}, -3, 3}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(If you don't know the angle, @rcollyer's answer seems the more useful one).

Answer (score 6):

Another approach to solving your problem would be to use the MultivariateStatistics package, which includes the EllipsoidQuantile function. Here's an example:

```
Needs["MultivariateStatistics`"]

fixations = {{19.4688, 17.4281}, {18.0563, 21.7156}, {13.0219, 
24.7219}, {22.9594, 25.5219}, {28.5406, 24.6719}, {27.0688, 
17.1656}, {27.6781, 16.325}, {28.9281, 10.7719}, {16.025, 
13.6625}, {19.1313, 17.1094}};

e50 = EllipsoidQuantile[fixations, 0.5]; (* use the median ellipse for this example *)
```

Now extract the ellipse axes and plot it:

```
major1 = e50[[1]] + e50[[3]]\[Transpose].{e50[[2, 1]], 0}; (* construct the major and minor axes for plotting *)
major2 = e50[[1]] - e50[[3]]\[Transpose].{e50[[2, 1]], 0};
minor1 = e50[[1]] + e50[[3]]\[Transpose].{0, e50[[2, 2]]};
minor2 = e50[[1]] - e50[[3]]\[Transpose].{0, e50[[2, 2]]};

Show[
 ListPlot[fixations, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> {All, {10, 30}}],
 Graphics[{Red, Thick, e50}],
 Graphics[{Red, Thick, Line[{major1, major2}]}],
 Graphics[{Red, Thick, Line[{minor1, minor2}]}]
 ]
```

[image]

Your example data doesn't have many points which makes it difficult (for me at least) to visualize the answer. Assuming the data are Normally distributed, you can generate some extra points this way:

```
mean = e50[[1]];
covMatrice = {{34.925, -10.21}, {-10.21, 22.462}};
\[ScriptCapitalD] = MultinormalDistribution[mean, covMatrice];
data = RandomVariate[\[ScriptCapitalD], 1000];
Histogram3D[data]
```

[image]

```
e50 = EllipsoidQuantile[data, 0.5];
major1 = e50[[1]] + e50[[3]]\[Transpose].{e50[[2, 1]], 0};
major2 = e50[[1]] - e50[[3]]\[Transpose].{e50[[2, 1]], 0};
minor1 = e50[[1]] + e50[[3]]\[Transpose].{0, e50[[2, 2]]};
minor2 = e50[[1]] - e50[[3]]\[Transpose].{0, e50[[2, 2]]};

Show[
 ListPlot[data, AspectRatio -> Automatic,PlotRange -> {All, {10, 30}}],
 Graphics[{Red, Thick, e50}],
 Graphics[{Red, Thick, Line[{major1, major2}]}],
 Graphics[{Red, Thick, Line[{minor1, minor2}]}]
 ]
```

[image]