# How to draw confidence ellipse from a covariance matrix?

Tags: graphics, probability-or-statistics, guidelines

I am studying a two-dimensional dataset, whose mean vector and covariance matrix are the following:

```
mean = {0.968479, 0.020717}
cov = {{0.0000797131, 0.000069929},{0.0000699293, 0.00174702}}
```

I want to generate a contour plot of the 95% confidence ellipse.

Comment: Is this about Mathematica, a software? related. [51163](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51163/5478)

Comment: Please look at this   http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2411/showing-the-correlation-of-two-variables-using-a-plot

Comment: Why not use [`EllipsoidQuantile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/MultivariateStatistics/ref/EllipsoidQuantile.html) on your dataset?

Comment: Did you look at this?  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/794/plot-ellipse-based-on-eigensystem/867#867

Comment: @MichaelE2 That's an excellent point about `EllipsoidQuantile`; thanks for bringing this up. In my understanding, however, that function answers a subtly different question. I expanded my answer below to cover this point as well.

Comment: @AbhijitSaha I wonder if you have had a chance to look over my answer below. Is that what you were looking for? If so, I'd appreciate it if you would consider accepting it. Otherwise, please let me know!

Comment: @MacroB thanks a lot. This is what i exactly wanted to know.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that my answer works for you. I'd be honored if you could accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### The executive summary

You can use the built-in `Ellipsoid` function directly with your calculated mean and covariance. For 95% confidence, use:

```
Ellipsoid[mean, cov Quantile[ChiSquareDistribution[2], 0.95]]
```

That expression returns an `Ellipsoid` object that you can visualize as an `Epilog` to a `ListPlot`, or as an argument to `Graphics` (further formatting below).

Ellipsoids for other common critical values can be obtained in the same way. Note the different multipliers to `cov`:

```
90% :   Ellipsoid[mean, cov Quantile[ChiSquareDistribution[2], 0.9]]
95% :   Ellipsoid[mean, cov Quantile[ChiSquareDistribution[2], 0.95]]
99% :   Ellipsoid[mean, cov Quantile[ChiSquareDistribution[2], 0.99]]
```

### A more detailed answer

First let me start by mentioning that a covariance matrix must be symmetric. You have a missing digit in `cov[[1,2]]` that makes your orignal one non-symmetric; I assume that it's a typo and will use the symmetric version below:

```
 mean = {0.968479, 0.020717};
 cov  = {{0.0000797131, 0.000069929}, {0.0000699293, 0.00174702}}
```

The easiest way to generate an ellipsoid with the right location and alignment given your distribution is to feed the mean and covariance directly to the `Ellipsoid` function, simply as `Ellipsoid[mean, cov]`. The resulting `Ellipsoid` is a graphical primitive, so it can be plotted on top of your data using e.g. `Epilog` or `Graphics`.

To get a practical example, let us generate and plot some random points from your distribution, assuming that it is normal.

```
 SeedRandom[1];
 sampledata = RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[mean, cov], 2500];
 
 ListPlot[
   sampledata,
   PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.05], 
   AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> None, Frame -> True,
   Epilog -> {Opacity[0], EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}], Ellipsoid[mean, cov]}
 ]
```

[image: Data and single-wide ellipsoid]

As you can see, however, an `Ellipsoid` that is "one covariance wide", as the one we plotted, contains only a small fraction of the sampled points (only roughly 40% of the points, see below). Instead you requested an ellipsoid containing 95% of the points from your distribution. **We need a wider** `Ellipsoid` **for that: but how wide?**

We can figure that out by using the probability distribution function (PDF) for your multivariate distribution. We can integrate the PDF over a parametric ellipsoidal region to calculate what fraction of the samples falls within that region. Let's consider a two-dimensional `MultinormalDistribution`, with zero average and covariance expressed by `{{sigmax^2, rho sigmax sigmay}, {rho sigmax sigmay, sigmay^2}}`, where `sigmax` and `sigmay` are the standard deviations associated with each of the two independent variables, and `rho` is the correlation coefficient between the two variables. The standard deviations are positive numbers, and 0 <= `rho` <= 1.

Here we calculate an expression for the fraction of points found within a two-dimensional ellipse centered around zero (the mean of this distribution) and "*n* covariances wide" (notice the `n` factor in the `Ellipsoid`'s descriptor. The integration is carried out over the region defined by that "*n*-wide" ellipse.

```
gencovar = {{sigmax^2, rho sigmax sigmay}, {rho sigmax sigmay, sigmay^2}};

Assuming[
  {n > 0, sigmax > 0, sigmay > 0, 0 <= rho < 1},
  Simplify[
   Integrate[
      PDF[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, gencovar], {x, y}],
      {x, y} \[Element] Ellipsoid[{0, 0}, n gencovar]
    ]
  ]
 ]
 
 (* 1-E^(-n/2) *)
```

Now let's tabulate the value of that expression for a few `n`.

```
 TableForm[#, TableAlignments -> {Right, Top}] &@
  Table[{ToString@n <> "x cov", ToString@Round[100 %, 1] <> "%"}, {n, 1, 9, 1}]
 
 (* 
 1x cov   39%
 2x cov   63%
 3x cov   78%
 4x cov   86%
 5x cov   92%
 6x cov   95%
 7x cov   97%
 8x cov   98%
 9x cov   99%  *)
```

This means that our original "single-wide" Ellipsoid contained only 39% of the samples; **to get 95% inclusion we need a *6x wide* `Ellipsoid`**.

Let's plot that for your original distribution (notice the all-important 6x factor in the `Ellipsoid` definition):

```
 ListPlot[
   sampledata,
   PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.05], 
   AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> None, Frame -> True,
   Epilog -> {Opacity[0], EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}], Ellipsoid[mean, 6 cov]}
 ]
```

[image: Data with 95% confidence ellipsoid]

Finally, we can also confirm this by **explicitly counting** the samples that fall within this `Ellipsoid`. The expression `Select[sampledata, RegionMember[Ellipsoid[mean, n cov]]]` allows us to select those samples in `sampledata` that lie within the geometric region defined by the "6x wide" `Ellipsoid[mean, 6 cov]`.

```
 N@Length@Select[sampledata, RegionMember[Ellipsoid[mean, 6 cov]]] / Length@sampledata
 
 (* 0.9544 *)
```

As expected from our previous calculations, **approximately 95% of the points reside within the 6x Ellipsoid** we defined.

For clarity, `Length@Select[sampledata, RegionMember[Ellipsoid[mean, n cov]]]` is the number of points lying within the `Ellipsoid` region. `Length@sampledata` is the total number of points in our sample. `N` is there to obtain an approximate numerical answer, rather than a symbolic one.

### Why not use `EllipsoidQuantile`?

[`EllipsoidQuantile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/MultivariateStatistics/ref/EllipsoidQuantile.html) is a function available in the [`MultivariateStatistics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/MultivariateStatistics/guide/MultivariateStatisticsPackage.html) package that was mentioned by @Michael E2 in a [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/81061/how-to-draw-confidence-ellipse-from-a-covariance-matrix/81128#comment219575_81061) as a possible solution to this problem. `EllipsoidQuantile[dataset, q]` returns an Ellipsoid centered on the mean of `dataset` and scaled to contain a fraction *q* of the `dataset`.

At a glance, this would seem exactly what the OP asked, but this function behaves in a subtly different way. In my understanding, it treats `dataset` as the *entire population*, rather than as a sample from a larger population. If the  sample available is large and it represents the population well, then the results of the two methods will be essentially indistinguishable. However, the two methods will give noticeably **different results for smaller samples and high levels of confidence** *q*.

I also have two more practical reasons not to use the EllipsoidQuantile function. First, it is difficult to apply styles to its output, although I have never been able to pinpoint why exactly. Additionally, some definitions in `MultivariateStatistics` seem to shadow definitions of functions that have since transitioned to built-in status, e.g. `PrincipalComponents` and `MultinormalDistribution`, so I'd rather not load the package unless it's absolutely necessary.

Here is some `Manipulate` code that allows one to compare the two results on the `sampledata` I generated above, and an example of when the two approaches differ considerably.

```
Needs["MultivariateStatistics`"]

Manipulate[
 Show[{
   ListPlot[
    sampledata[[1 ;; ;; every]],
    Axes -> None, Frame -> True,
    Epilog -> 
     Inset[Style["alpha = " <> ToString@alpha, FontSize -> 14], Scaled[{0.85, 0.9}]]
    ],
   Graphics[{
     (* using EllipsoidQuantile *)
     EllipsoidQuantile[sampledata[[1 ;; ;; every]], alpha],
     (* Using the Ellipsoid method outlined above *)
     {Opacity[0], EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}], 
            Ellipsoid[
              Mean@sampledata[[1 ;; ;; every]], 
              Evaluate[n /. First@Quiet@Solve[1 - E^(-n/2) == alpha, n]] Covariance@sampledata[[1 ;; ;; every]]
            ]
        }
   }]
  }, PlotRange -> {{0.93, 1.01}, {-0.17, 0.24}}
 ],
 
 (* Manipulate variables *)
 {{alpha, 0.95, "\[Alpha] value"}, 0.9, 0.99, 0.01, Appearance -> "Open"},
 {{every, 100, "points"}, {1 -> "All", 10 -> "250", 20 -> "125", 50 -> "50", 100 -> "25", 250 -> "10"}, ControlType -> SetterBar}
 ]
```

A sample output highlights the difference: in red is the `Ellipsoid` result, and in black the `EllipsoidQuantile` output:

[image: Manipulate to compare Ellipsoid and EllipsoidQuantile]

Comment: Very nice explanation, +1

Comment: @bobthechemist Thank you! I appreciate the support, especially from a fellow chemist!

Comment: I appreciate the difference between the sample and population, but as far as styling, the output is an `Ellipsoid`.  I don't see how that could be more difficult than your constructed `Ellipsoid`.  I, too, am annoyed by the shadowing.  They should promote it to the ``"System`"`` context like the most of the rest of statistics.  (+1)

Comment: @MichaelE2 `EllipsoidQuantile` does *not* actually return a standard `Ellipsoid` object. For instance, `EllipsoidQuantile[sampledata,0.9]` returns `Ellipsoid[{0.968, 0.0214}, {0.0867, 0.0185}, {{0.0422, 0.999}, {-0.999, 0.0422}}]`: this is a call to `Ellipsoid` with *three* arguments, instead of the *two* expected by the [built-in function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ellipsoid.html). This seems linked to an [older `Ellipsoid` function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/MultivariateStatistics/ref/Ellipsoid.html) within `MultivariateStatistics` that used three arguments.

Comment: @MichaelE2 The `MultivariateStatistics` package loads that older definition as well, so its `EllipsoidQuantile` function still works apparently seamlessly. However, this older `Ellipsoid` does not play nice with others: `EdgeForm` and `FaceForm` have no effect on it; `Opacity` applies to its edge, and not to its face as it does for the built-in `Ellipsoid`; this "three-parameter" `Ellipsoid` cannot be used as an `Epilog` to e.g. `ListPlot` (an attempt returns `Ellipsoid is not a graphics primitive or directive`). Sneaky!

Comment: @MichaelE2 However, I'm not very adept at looking into the guts of the MMA environment yet, so if I'm on a completely wrong path, I'd appreciate any pointers!

Comment: @MarcoB No, you're right, thanks. I didn't notice those details. The built-in `Ellipsoid[mean, 6 cov]` is displayed as `GeometricTransformation[Disk[{0, 0}], {{{0.02186958161465372, 0.}, {0.019185360167972444`, 0.10056859328450993`}}, {0.968479, 0.020717}}]` and the older one is converted to a closed, styled `Line` object inside `Graphics`. For instance, one can use this with `ListPlot`: `Epilog -> {First@Graphics[{Red, EllipsoidQuantile[sampledata, 0.9]}]}`. (The menu command Cell > Show Expression and adding `// InputForm` are some ways to investigate "What happened?".)

Comment: @MichaelE2 That is very insightful. I had an inkling that the old `Ellipsoid` really had to be just a line rather than a disk. I am glad to see that confirmed, and to learn something new in the process!

Comment: @MichaelE2 Just a side note, `Graphics` cannot handle multiple ``MultivariateStatistics`Ellipsoid``s in _v11.2_, while it can in _v9_. Sample code: `data = RandomReal[1, {10, 2}];
q = EllipsoidQuartiles[data];
q // Graphics`  I guess the issue is introduced since _v10_.

Comment: @xzczd Strange. `Graphics /@ q // Show` works.  `Graphics[Ellipsoid[..]]` works but not `Graphics[{Ellipsoid[..]}]` does. It's probably a bug, since the example in the docs does not work, either.

Answer (score 4):

Working code with Ellipsoid and Eigensystem

```
<< MultivariateStatistics`
mean = {0, 0};
cov = {{1, 0.7}, {0.7, 1}};
sampledata = RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[mean, cov], 2500];
Show[
 ListPlot[sampledata, PlotRange -> All],
 Graphics[
  Ellipsoid[{0, 0}, Sqrt[2*6*Eigensystem[cov][[1]]], 
   Eigensystem[cov][[2]]]],
 PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, AspectRatio -> 1
 ]
```

F

Comment: A bit wasteful to call `Eigensystem[]` twice, no?

Comment: Yes, it is! You can replace it with the computation of eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Either one can precompute the two things before. Sorry, I'm a lazy guy!