# Manipulating the output of EllipsoidQuantile

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I am trying to manipulate the output of [`EllipsoidQuantile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/MultivariateStatistics/ref/EllipsoidQuantile.html) to find the area in the next line.

I can easily find the 95% confidence interval and this generates an ellipsoid, but I would like to extract the axis without copy and pasting.

```
data = {{-3.17, 272.35}, {.67, 271.54},..........};
elips = EllipsoidQuantile[data, 0.95]
```

the output is then

> ```
> Ellipsoid[{{-.578,272},{2.88,0.62},{-.09,0.12},{-.12,-.099}}]
> ```

I would like to extract the second row of data(major and minor axis).

Comment: [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) ? And please add complete examples.

Comment: As a word of caution, you might care to know that `EllipsoidQuantile` uses an obsolete definition of the `Ellipsoid` function, as you will notice if you compare the three-argument results you get with the current two-argument definition in the documentation. Take a look at this question [How to draw confidence ellipse from a covariance matrix?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/81128/27951) for a way of drawing those ellipsoids that also doesn't require you to use the `MultivariateStatistics` package.

Answer (score 1):

Let me generate some random bivariate toy data :

```
SeedRandom[1]
newdata = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[{10, 25}, {1, 5}, 0.7], 100];
```

Take a look at my answer to this question: [How to draw confidence ellipse from a covariance matrix?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/81061/27951). You will see that you can obtain a 95% confidence ellipsoid as follows:

```
ellipsoid95 = Ellipsoid[Mean[newdata], 6 Covariance[newdata]]

(* Out: Ellipsoid[{9.99033, 25.6897}, {{6.17123, 20.9226}, {20.9226, 137.338}}] *)
```

You can plot this with your data:

```
ListPlot[
  newdata, 
  Epilog -> {Opacity[0], EdgeForm[{Gray, Thick, Dashed}], ellipsoid95},
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.075], Frame -> True, Axes -> False
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This generates a "new" `Ellipsoid` object that plays nice with the convenient geometric region functions. For instance, you can then obtain its area simply with the `Area` function:

```
Area[ellipsoid95]

(* Out: 63.596 *)
```