# Plotting confidence interval from P values (from DistributionFitTest) for 2 parameters

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, distributions

I have a data set I'd like to adjust with 2 parameters, then compare that to another set of data.  By using `NMaximixe` with `DistributionFitTest`, I'm able to determine the best fit of parameters.  Great, now I'd like to do something like plot a `ContourPlot` of the 2D parameter space to show a 1-sigma, 2-sigma, and 3-sigma confidence interval for possible choices of parameters.

However, `DistributionFitTest` only returns P-values and test statistics.  I am still a complete noob when it comes to stats, so I have no idea how to determine confidence intervals from this...

A quick example that you can copy and paste:

```
Clear["Global`*"]

NumPerSet = 1000;

(* This is the first "double-hump" distribution *)
set1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[6, 1.2], NumPerSet];
set2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[11, 1.2], NumPerSet];
data1 = Join[set1, set2];

(* This is like data1 but "shifted" to the left by 1 *)
set3 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[5, 1.2], NumPerSet];
set4 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[10, 1.2], NumPerSet];
data2 = Join[set3, set4];

(* Now apply a scale factor to the data2 set *)
data2 = data2 0.9;

(* Create some plottable distributions *)
skd1 = KernelMixtureDistribution[data1];
skd2 = KernelMixtureDistribution[data2];

(* Show each distribution and the associated histogram *)
Show[Plot[{PDF[skd1, x], PDF[skd2, x]}, {x, 0, 15}, Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> "The Setup"], Histogram[{data1, data2}, Automatic, "PDF", ChartLegends -> {"data1", "data2"}]]

(* Now show a plot of the parameter space, where the peak should be around x = 1, y = 0.9 *)
ContourPlot[DistributionFitTest[(data1 - shift) scale, skd2, "PValue"], {shift, 0.8, 1.2}, {scale, 0.8, 1}]
```

I could spit out a test statistic for a grid of points instead (and try to fit lines to this), but I don't know how to calculate the confidence interval from P-values or test statistics.  Is there a built-in method, or a way I could even brute force it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By now I think you know what my comment will be:  Get thee to a Statistician!  Your approach is imaginative but certainly not commonly accepted statistical practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a bootstrap approach where you don't have to assume any particular form of distribution.  (And, yes, the code is made to show things step-by-step rather than being efficient.  However, the 1,000 bootstrap samples takes only the blink of an eye.)

```
(* First, get an estimate of the shift and scale parameters *)
momScale = StandardDeviation[data2]/StandardDeviation[data1]
momShift = Mean[data1] - Mean[data2]/momScale
(* Or use the following *)
(* miScale=InterquartileRange[data2]/InterquartileRange[data1]
miShift=Median[data1]-Median[data2]/miScale *)

(* Now run 1,000 bootstrap samples *)
nBoot = 1000;
scale1 = 0;
scale2 = 0;
shift1 = 0;
shift2 = 0;
scaleXshift = 0;
Do[
 (* Take a bootstrap sample from each dataset *)
 d1 = RandomChoice[data1, NumPerSet];
 d2 = RandomChoice[data2, NumPerSet];

 (* Estimate parameters from the bootstrap sample *)
 bootScale = StandardDeviation[d1]/StandardDeviation[d2];
 bootShift = Mean[d1] - Mean[d2]/bootScale;

 (* Bump all of the counters used to estimate the standard errors *)
 scale1 = scale1 + bootScale;
 scale2 = scale2 + bootScale^2;
 shift1 = shift1 + bootShift;
 shift2 = shift2 + bootShift^2;
 scaleXshift = scaleXshift + bootScale*bootShift,
{i, nBoot}]

(* Standard error for scale *)
seScale = ((scale2 - scale1^2/nBoot)/(nBoot - 1))^0.5
(* Standard error for shift*)
seShift = ((shift2 - shift1^2/nBoot)/(nBoot - 1))^0.5
(* Correlation between estimators of shift and scale *)
corrScaleShift = ((scaleXshift - scale1 shift1/nBoot)/(nBoot - 1))/(seScale seShift)
```

Comment: Awesome, that's quick and easy.  Now... plotting this... In theory, I should be able to position the "peak" at (momShift,momScale) on a 2D plot of the parameter space, and see rings go out at 1/2/3-sigma, but the exact shape/rotation of such a contour plot eludes me.  For example, is it rotated at all?

Comment: Forget 1/2/3-sigma:  at best that applies to the one dimensional case.  One is assuming/hoping that a bivariate normal distribution will closely approximate the bivariate distribution of the estimators of the scale and shift parameters.  Search this site for "bivariate normal contours" or see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/153511/1-sigma-contour-plot-for-a-two-dimensional-gaussian/153516#153516.

Comment: If you can bear with me a while longer:  Forget the p-value approach, too.  Your problem as stated involves "estimation" rather than "hypothesis testing".

Comment: I am 100% OK abandoning the P-value approach, and you're right, I'm just trying to get good estimations.  I will refer to your other link for more help with the contours.  Thank you again!!