# Smooth Density Histogram with probability areas

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

As an example, for a normal distribution everyone knows that 68% will fall within one standard deviation away from the center and so on.

The following code will give me a 2D Normal distribution and plot it.

```
a = Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1]], {i, 22000}, {j, 2}];

{SmoothDensityHistogram[a, PlotLegends -> Automatic, Mesh -> 3], 
 SmoothHistogram3D[a]}
```

[image: 2D Normal Distribution]

The question I wish to answer is "how can I calculate the probability contained above a specific mesh line?".  Of course for this particular case I could add up the area under the contour curve, for example I should be able to recover the one standard deviation percentage by adding up everything under the contour curve of the SmoothHistogram3D plot inside the area $x^2 + y^2 < 1^2$, and I could find the next by adding the area $ 1^2<x^2 + y^2 < 2^2$

So now onto my actual more difficult problem, I'm plotting the Smooth Density Histogram of a double pendulum (particularly the location of the bottom pendulum).

The following code:

```
deqns = {Subscript[m, 1] x1''[
  t] == (\[Lambda]1[t]/Subscript[l, 1]) x1[
   t] - (\[Lambda]2[t]/Subscript[l, 2]) (x2[t] - x1[t]), 
  Subscript[m, 1] y1''[
  t] == (\[Lambda]1[t]/Subscript[l, 1]) y1[
   t] - (\[Lambda]2[t]/Subscript[l, 2]) (y2[t] - y1[t]) - 
  Subscript[m, 1] g, 
  Subscript[m, 2] x2''[
  t] == (\[Lambda]2[t]/Subscript[l, 2]) (x2[t] - x1[t]), 
  Subscript[m, 2] y2''[
  t] == (\[Lambda]2[t]/Subscript[l, 2]) (y2[t] - y1[t]) - 
  Subscript[m, 2] g};

aeqns = {x1[t]^2 + y1[t]^2 == 
  Subscript[l, 1]^2, (x2[t] - x1[t])^2 + (y2[t] - y1[t])^2 == 
  Subscript[l, 2]^2};

ics = {x1[0] == 1, y1[0] == 0, y1'[0] == 0, x2[0] == 1, y2[0] == -1, 
  y2'[0] == 0};

params = {g -> 9.81, Subscript[m, 1] -> 1, Subscript[m, 2] -> 1, 
  Subscript[l, 1] -> 1, Subscript[l, 2] -> 1};

soldp = First[
  NDSolve[{deqns, aeqns, ics} /. params, {x1, y1, x2, 
  y2, \[Lambda]1, \[Lambda]2}, {t, 0, 15000}, 
  Method -> {"IndexReduction" -> {"Pantelides", 
    "ConstraintMethod" -> "Projection"}}]];
```

Will give the solution to a double pendulum (where each pendulum is of length one).  ($t$ is really large so if you want to run it yourself feel free to bring it down an order of magnitude).

Here is the smooth histogram,

```
SmoothDensityHistogram[
  Map[Function[Evaluate[{x2[#], y2[#]} /. soldp]], 
   Range[0, 15000, 0.025]], Mesh -> 5, 
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 0.1}}]
```

[image: Density Probability Double Pendulum]

How can I label (and calculate) a specific region between mesh lines and so that 25% (or whatever it is) of the probability is between these two mesh lines (and so forth similar to the Normal distribution example above)?

Comment: something like [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/164490/125)?

Comment: [Related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/153511/1-sigma-contour-plot-for-a-two-dimensional-gaussian).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
soldp = First[NDSolve[{deqns, aeqns, ics} /. params, {x1, y1, x2, y2, λ1, λ2}, 
   {t, 0, 15000/2}, 
   Method -> {"IndexReduction" -> {"Pantelides", "ConstraintMethod" -> "Projection"}}]]; 
dt = Map[Function[Evaluate[{x2[#], y2[#]} /. soldp]], Range[0, 15000/2, 0.025]]; 
sdh1 = SmoothDensityHistogram[dt, Mesh -> 5, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 0.1}}]
```

[image]

Using the approach from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/164490/125) to a related q/a:

We define multivariate "quantiles" based on the height of the kernel density function. The function `volume[z]` gives the total probability of the set of points where density exceeds `z`. We find the density threshold levels corresponding to desired probability coverages (this part is very slow).

As an example, each of the two regions between the contour lines corresponding to 95%, 70% and 45% probabilities have total density 25%:

```
skdPDF = PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[dt]];
volume[z_?NumericQ] := Quiet@NIntegrate[skdPDF[{s, t}] Boole[skdPDF[{s, t}] >= z], 
  {s, -∞, ∞}, {t, -∞, ∞}]

{t95, t70, t45} = Quiet[FindRoot[volume[z] - # == 0, {z, 0, 1}]] & /@ {.95, .70, .45}
```

> {{z -> 0.0705034}, {z -> 0.128013}, {z -> 0.16069}}

```
mesh = {{{z /. t95, Red}, {z /. t70, Green}, {z /. t45, Purple}}};
sdh2 = SmoothDensityHistogram[dt, 
  MeshFunctions -> {skdPDF[{#, #2}] &}, 
  Mesh -> mesh, MeshStyle -> Thick, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 0.1}}]
```

[image]

The regions colored `Yellow` and `Orange` each have 25% probability coverage:

```
SmoothDensityHistogram[dt, MeshFunctions -> {skdPDF[{#, #2}] &}, 
 Mesh -> mesh, MeshStyle -> Thick, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 0.1}}, 
 MeshShading -> {None, Yellow, Orange, None}]
```

[image]

```
SmoothHistogram3D[dt, BoxRatios -> 1, Mesh -> mesh, 
 MeshStyle -> Thick, MeshShading -> {White, Yellow, Orange, White}, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

```
Show[sdh1, Graphics[Cases[Normal[sdh2], {dir__, _Line}, All]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted.  I did a search earlier and did not see the solution you referenced at the beginning.

Comment: @Josh,my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.