# Computing Credible Region (Highest Posterior Density) from Empirical Distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, data

I have a dataset where values are distributed in some experimental way, not following any theoretical distribution. The dataset could be unimodal with a nicely defined single peak or multimodal with dips or various depths. What would be a fast algorithm to approximate the 80-90-95-99% (pick one) credible region? Computational performance is valued SIGNIFICANTLY over accuracy. Accuracy to +/-1% is reasonable, as the data already has significant bias/variance in it.

If you're not familiar with credible regions, it is the interval (or multiple intervals!!!) where the highest probability mass occurs. The slow way to compute this is `NIntegrate[]` as the sum of the areas under the tallest parts of PDF should add up to the level you are trying to achieve (e.g. 95%).

Visually speaking, the question is "How high/low should we set the bar, so that the area under intersecting intervals is ~0.95(+/-1)%?"

Currently, my top idea is to divide data into a large number of bins (say N/100), then sort bins and keep adding largest bins to a list until the total of selectel bin counts is greater than the desired credibility. Then sort bins by their dependent variable value and group any continuous values into a single interval, thus creating the list of intervals which span the highest density region. Am I overcomplicating things? And is there perhaps a built in function, of which I'm unaware, which would solve this task out-of-the-box?

**Unimodal CI vs HDR:**
[image: Unimodal confidence interval vs highest density region]

**Multimodal CI vs HDR:**
[image: Multimodal confidence interval vs highest density region]

Comment: Sample data and corresponding desired interval/region would be helpful.

Comment: [related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/164490/125)

Comment: Also related:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/240749/how-to-find-95-credible-interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for something speedier (but maybe at the cost of losing some accuracy) that gives the credible interval(s), then fitting a nonparametric density estimate and evaluating that along a dense, equally-spaced set of intervals might be the way to go.  (This is somewhat as you suggested with the raw data but takes advantage of the assumption of the samples coming from a relatively smooth probability distribution.)   And I'm certain that the code below can be made more efficient (and with more clarity).

```
(* Generate some data from a distribution with two peaks *)
SeedRandom[12345];
d = MixtureDistribution[{2, 1}, {NormalDistribution[], NormalDistribution[5, 1/2]}];
x = RandomVariate[d, 1000];

(* Fit a nonparametric density estimate *)
skd = SmoothKernelDistribution[x];

(* Generate a table of density values over an equally-spaced set of intervals *)
bw = skd[[2, 3]]; (* Get bandwidth to allow for expansion a bit beyond the  observed data *)
zmin = Min[x] - 4 bw;
zmax = Max[x] + 4 bw;
n = 1000; (* Number of equally-spaced intervals *)
y = Table[{i, PDF[skd, zmin + i (zmax - zmin)/n]}, {i, 0, n}];

(* Sort by density values, accumulate, and standardize to sum to 1 *)
y = SortBy[y, Last];
y[[All, 2]] = Accumulate[y[[All, 2]]]/Total[y[[All, 2]]];

(* Set desired credible level *)
c = 0.95;

(* Find indicies of lower and upper bounds for the credible set *)
yy = SortBy[Select[y, #[[2]] >= (1 - c) &], First][[All, 1]];
d = Differences[yy];
lower = Transpose[{yy, Join[{2}, d]}];
upper = Transpose[{yy, Join[d, {2}]}];
(* Lower and upper indices are found when there is a gap of more than 1 index *)
lower = Select[lower, #[[2]] > 1 &][[All, 1]];
upper = Select[upper, #[[2]] > 1 &][[All, 1]];

(* Convert from indices to associated values *)
lower = zmin + # (zmax - zmin)/n & /@ lower;
upper = zmin + # (zmax - zmin)/n & /@ upper;

(* Create list of credible intervals *)
hpd = Transpose[{lower, upper}];
Print[100 c, "% credible interval(s): ", hpd]
(* 95.% credible interval(s): {{-2.29102,2.39434},{3.57287,6.34672}} *)

(* Plot the results *)
hpdPlotData = {{#[[1]], 0}, {#[[2]], 0}} & /@ hpd;
Show[Plot[PDF[skd, z], {z, zmin, zmax}],
 ListPlot[hpdPlotData, PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.01]], Joined -> True]]
```

[image: Fitted distribution and credible intervals]

Comment: You're right, this is indeed ridiculously speedy! At the cost of slightly higher memory consumption for larger sets and a tiny accuracy tradeoff. 
At 500k samples and n=10k slices it's actually ~15X faster than the FindRoot solution and produces clear intervals with nearly identical values. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 7):

```
ClearAll[area, skdPDF]
SeedRandom[1]
data = Join[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 200], 
   RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[4, 1/2], 200]];
skd = SmoothKernelDistribution[data];
skdPDF[s_?NumericQ] := PDF[skd, s];
area[z_?NumericQ] := Quiet @ NIntegrate[Piecewise[{{skdPDF[s], skdPDF[s] >= z}}], 
   {s, -∞, ∞}]
{q80, q90, q95, q99} = Quantile[skd, #] & /@ 
   {{.1, .9}, {.05, .95}, {.025, .975}, {.005, .995}};
{t80, t90, t95, t99} = Quiet[FindRoot[area[z] - # == 0., {z, 0., .5}]] & /@ 
   {.8, .9, .95, .99};

Plot[{skdPDF[x], ConditionalExpression[skdPDF[x], skdPDF[x] >= #]}, {x, -5, 10}, 
    Filling -> {2 -> {Axis, {None, Yellow}}}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
    MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, Mesh -> {{#}}, MeshStyle -> None, 
    MeshShading -> {Red, Blue}, GridLines -> {#2, {#}}, 
    GridLinesStyle -> {Dashed, Thick}, 
    Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}, ImageSize -> 350, 
    Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> Style["Prob: " <> ToString@#3, 16], 
    Axes -> False, 
    FrameTicks -> {{{{#, Style[Round[#, .001], 14]}}, Automatic}, 
       {Automatic, Automatic}}] & @@@ 
  Transpose[{z /. {t80, t90, t95, t99}, {q80, q90, q95, q99},
    {.8, .9, .95, .99}}] // // Grid[Partition[#, 2]] &
```

[image]

Comment: Great solution but plots are misleading. Yellow area should be between PDF and x-axis.

Comment: @Okkes, thank you; fixed now.

Comment: PERFECT answer! Thank you! Using `HistogramDistribution` or even SKD with a smaller bandwidth provides really neat results. Adding `AccuracyGoal->2, PrecisionGoal->2` to `FindRoot` makes performance go through the roof. Though I feel there's some optimization I'm missing, which would make it go even faster.

Comment: @kglr  How do I extract the intervals where skdPDF is >= z? Thanks!

Comment: It's a worthy answer. The solution is nearly universal and very fast. Thanks again! What I actually need is a numerical approach, not graphical, so that I can compute a test whether a given sample feels into the range or not. I guess the simple way would be to just say `skdPDF[sample]>=z` and not have to extract actual intervals.

Answer (score 4):

I made this couple months ago. It is not perfect but may give you some idea. I haven't try bimodal/multimodal one.

```
hDI[α_, a_, b_] := 
 Module[{}, f[x_] := PDF[NormalDistribution[], x];
  sol = {c1, c2} /. 
    Assuming[
     c1 ∈ Reals && c2 ∈ Reals && c1 <= 0 && 
      c2 >= 0 , 
     FindRoot[{Integrate[f[x], {x, c1, c2}] == α, 
       f[c2] == f[c1]}, {{c1, a}, {c2, b}}, MaxIterations -> 1000]];
  Show[Plot[f[x], {x, First@sol, Last@sol}, Axes -> {True, False}, 
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> All, 
    Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> LightBlue], 
          Plot[f[x], {x, -3, 3}], 
   Graphics[{Arrowheads[{-0.04, 0.04}], 
     Arrow[{{First@sol, f[First@sol]}, {Last@sol, f[Last@sol]}}], 
     Text[Round[First@sol, 0.01], {First@sol - 0.3, f[First@sol]}], 
     Text[Round[Last@sol, 0.01], {Last@sol + 0.3, f[Last@sol]}], 
     Text[Round[α 100] "% HDI", {Mean[{First@sol, Last@sol}], 
       f@Mean[{First@sol, Last@sol}]/2}]}]]]

hDI[0.95, -1, 1]
```

[image]

```
hDI[α_, a_, b_] := 
 Module[{}, data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 10000]; 
  f[x_] := PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[data], x];
  sol = {c1, c2} /. 
    Assuming[
     c1 ∈ Reals && c2 ∈ Reals && c1 <= 0 && 
      c2 >= 0 , 
     FindRoot[{Integrate[f[x], {x, c1, c2}] == α, 
       f[c2] == f[c1]}, {{c1, a}, {c2, b}}, MaxIterations -> 1000]];
  Show[Plot[f[x], {x, First@sol, Last@sol}, Axes -> {True, False}, 
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> All, 
   Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> LightBlue, 
   Plot[f[x], {x, -3, 3}], 
   Graphics[{Arrowheads[{-0.04, 0.04}], 
     Arrow[{{First@sol, f[First@sol]}, {Last@sol, f[Last@sol]}}], 
     Text[Round[First@sol, 0.01], {First@sol - 0.3, f[First@sol]}], 
     Text[Round[Last@sol, 0.01], {Last@sol + 0.3, f[Last@sol]}], 
     Text[Round[α 100] "% HDI", {Mean[{First@sol, Last@sol}], 
       f@Mean[{First@sol, Last@sol}]/2}]}]]]
hDI[0.95, -1, 1]
```

[image]

```
hDI[α_, a_, b_] := 
 Module[{}, f[x_] := PDF[GammaDistribution[2, 2], x];
  sol = {c1, c2} /. 
    Assuming[
     c1 ∈ Reals && c2 ∈ Reals && c1 >= 0 && 
      c2 >= 0 , 
     FindRoot[{Integrate[f[x], {x, c1, c2}] == α, 
       f[c2] == f[c1]}, {{c1, a}, {c2, b}}, MaxIterations -> 1000]];
  Show[Plot[f[x], {x, First@sol, Last@sol}, Axes -> {True, False}, 
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> All, 
    Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> LightBlue, 
   Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 13}], 
   Graphics[{Arrowheads[{-0.04, 0.04}], 
     Arrow[{{First@sol, f[First@sol]}, {Last@sol, f[Last@sol]}}], 
     Text[Round[First@sol, 0.01], {First@sol - 0.3, f[First@sol]}], 
     Text[Round[Last@sol, 0.01], {Last@sol + 0.3, f[Last@sol]}], 
     Text[Round[α 100] "% HDI", {Mean[{First@sol, Last@sol}], 
       f@Mean[{First@sol, Last@sol}]/2}]}]]]

hDI[0.95, 2, 6]
```

[image]

```
hDI[α_, a_] := 
 Module[{}, f[x_] := PDF[ExponentialDistribution[2], x];
  sol = c1 /. 
    Assuming[c1 ∈ Reals && c1 >= 0 , 
     FindRoot[{Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, c1}] == α}, {c1, a}, 
      MaxIterations -> 1000]];
  Show[Plot[f[x], {x, 0, sol}, Axes -> {True, False}, 
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> All, 
    Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> LightBlue, 
   Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2}], 
   Graphics[{Arrowheads[{-0.04, 0.04}], 
     Arrow[{{0, f[sol]}, {sol, f[sol]}}], 
     Text[Round[0, 0.01], {0, f[sol]}], 
     Text[Round[sol, 0.01], {sol + 0.1, f[sol]}], 
     Text[Round[α 100] "% HDI", {Mean[{0, sol}], 
       f@Mean[{0, sol}]/2}]}]]]

hDI[0.8, 1]
```

[image]

```
d = 
  SmoothKernelDistribution[
   N[Log[Table[GenomeData[i, "SequenceLength"], {i, 41}]]]];

f[x_] := PDF[d], x];

hDI[α_, a_, b_, c_, d_] := Module[{},
  sol = {c1, c2, c3, c4} /. 
    Assuming[
     c1 ∈ Reals && c2 ∈ Reals && 
      c3 ∈ Reals && c4 ∈ Reals && c1 >= 0 && 
      c2 >= 0 && c3 >= 0 && c24 >= 0, 
     FindRoot[{(Integrate[f[x], {x, c1, c2}] + 
          Integrate[f[x], {x, c3, c4}]) == α, 
       f[c1] == f[c2] == f[c3] == f[c4]}, {{c1, a}, {c2, b}, {c3, 
        c}, {c4, d}}, MaxIterations -> 1000]];
  Show[Plot[f[x], {x, sol[[1]], sol[[2]]}, Axes -> {True, False}, 
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> All, Filling -> Axis, 
    FillingStyle -> LightBlue], 
   Plot[f[x], {x, sol[[3]], sol[[4]]}, Axes -> {True, False}, 
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> All, Filling -> Axis, 
    FillingStyle -> LightBlue], Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 30}], 
   Graphics[{Arrowheads[{-0.02, 0.02}], 
     Arrow[{{sol[[1]], f[sol[[1]]]}, {sol[[2]], f[sol[[2]]]}}], 
     Arrow[{{sol[[3]], f[sol[[3]]]}, {sol[[4]], f[sol[[4]]]}}], 
     Text[Round[sol[[1]], 0.01], {sol[[1]] - 0.5, f[sol[[1]]]}], 
     Text[Round[sol[[2]], 0.01], {sol[[2]] + 0.6, f[sol[[2]]]}], 
     Text[Round[sol[[3]], 0.01], {sol[[3]] - 0.6, f[sol[[3]]]}], 
     Text[Round[sol[[4]], 0.01], {Last@sol + 0.6, f[sol[[4]]]}], 
     Text[Round[α 100] "% HDI", {Mean[{sol[[3]], sol[[4]]}], 
       f@Mean[{sol[[3]], sol[[4]]}]/2}]}]]]

hDI[0.8, 5, 11, 17, 21]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It's close to what hadand runs into mostly same problems I want to fix: (1) `Integrate` is really slow (`NIntegrate` is better, but still...) (2) You're looking for `f[c2] == f[c1]`, this would only work for distributions relatively close to Normal. What if you had LogNormal dist or even Exponential dist? Left side of ExpDist CR should be = 0 with f[c1] being at absolute maximum value for the PDF. (3) Using SKD for PDF is limited... plot SKD for exponentially distributed data, and you'll see why your CR will have a negative min value. Still, really appreciate your response!

Comment: @GregoryKlopper The "Bounded" option for `SmoothKernelDistribution` fixes the issue you raise about having negative values for a non-negative probability distribution.

Comment: Those are some great examples. Looks really good!