# Calculate the mean value from point inside a 2D contour

Tags: plotting, smoothing, averages

I saw a [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85213/94681) about creating contour lines over a smoothdensityhistogram plot. It really help me to create this kind of graphs.

I want to ask if is possible to extract only the points inside a certain contour to obtain, for example, mean values or desviation.

kind regards

Comment: What do you mean by "mean values" of the points inside a certain contour.  Mean location?  Mean height of the density curve?  Or are that additional attributes associated with each data point such as percent foliage cover, elevation, tree density, etc., for which you want a mean or standard deviation?

Comment: Yes mean location, or just extract these points in a array to do other calculations.

Comment: @ydd 's `splitUp` list created by using `Table` and `Select` shows how you can extract the points either between contours or inside or outside a particular contour.

Comment: Also note that a "mean location" could still be calculated from the bivariate density even if there were no data points within a particular contour.  This would be analogous to the mean of a truncated distribution.  I would think that after the trouble estimating a bivariate distribution that summary calculations would be done based on the estimated bivariate density.  The data points have done their job and it would be relying on the entity that you've estimated for future calculations.

Answer (score 2):

Using @Ian 's example from your [linked question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85213/72953):

---

Ian's part (except I added explicit `SeedRandom`)

```
SeedRandom[123];

*two dimensional data*) data = 
   RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.75], 200];

(*nonparametric density estimate*)
d = SmoothKernelDistribution[data];

(*logged density estimate at data*)
p = PDF[d, data];

(*quantile for countour height*)
q = 1 - {0.68, 0.95, 0.99};

c = Quantile[p, q];
```

---

Then create your quantile bounds by padding a 1 and a 0 to either end of `q`

```
cPad = PadLeft[c, Length@c + 1, 1];
cPad = PadRight[cPad, Length@cPad + 1, 0];
quantileBounds = Partition[cPad, 2, 1]
(*{{{1, 0.0759093}, {0.0759093, 0.0200241}, {0.0200241, 
  0.00849196}, {0.00849196, 0}}*)
```

And split up `data` based on which quantiles their PDF values fall between:

```
splitUp = 
Table[Select[data, Last[i] < PDF[d, #] <= First[i] &], {i, 
   quantileBounds}];
```

*(If you don't want to calculate the PDF again of all the data points, you could use `Position` instead but I feel this looks uglier than the `Select` implementation):*

```
splitUp = 
  Table[Part[data, 
    Flatten@Position[p, n_ /; Last[i] < n <= First[i]]], {i, 
    quantileBounds}];
```

Comparing mean and variances. As expected, we see the variance grow as you go out to more extreme quantiles:

```
Mean /@ splitUp

(*{{0.0116993, -0.147756}, {0.214602, 
  0.222228}, {-0.361543, -0.202958}, {-0.741956, -1.677}}*)

Variance /@ splitUp

(*{{0.382458, 0.346718}, {1.4757, 1.59431}, {2.1283, 3.82937}, {8.91892,
   2.63842}}*)
```

And plotting different point colors depending on quantiles:

```
nonEmptyContours = Select[splitUp, Length[#] > 0 &];
lpAll = ListPlot[nonEmptyContours, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Green, Orange, Red}];

Show[DensityPlot[PDF[d, {x, y}], ##], 
   ContourPlot[PDF[d, {x, y}], ##, Contours -> c, 
    ContourShading -> None], lpAll] &[{x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit:**
I think you were asking actually how to do this using [JimB's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85171/72953)
answer. The methodology is basically the same:

---

JimB's part (except adding explicit `SeedRandom` and set `c` to `contours`):

```
SeedRandom[123];
data = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.75], 100];
(*Calculate a nonparametric density estimate*)
d = SmoothKernelDistribution[data];

(*Evaluate the estimated density function over a grid of points and \
sort by the density values from high to low*)
pdf = Reverse[
   Sort[Flatten[
     Table[PDF[d, {x, y}], {x, -3, 3, 0.05}, {y, -3, 3, 0.05}]]]];

(*Create a table of cumulative pdf values that correspond to the \
volumes of interest*)
cdf = Accumulate[pdf]/Total[pdf];
contours = 
  pdf[[Flatten[
     Table[FirstPosition[cdf, 
       p_ /; p >= alpha], {alpha, {0.68, 0.95, 0.99}}]]]];

c = contours;
```

---

Then do everything the same as before. We can color the points based on their contours:

```
cPad = PadLeft[c, Length@c + 1, 1];
cPad = PadRight[cPad, Length@cPad + 1, 0];
quantileBounds = Partition[cPad, 2, 1];
splitUp = 
  Table[Select[data, Last[i] < PDF[d, #] <= First[i] &], {i, 
    quantileBounds}];

sdh = SmoothDensityHistogram[data, PlotRange -> All];
cp = ContourPlot[PDF[d, {x, y}], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
   Contours -> contours, ContourShading -> None, PlotRange -> All];
nonEmptyContours = Select[splitUp, Length[#] > 0 &];

coloredByContourPoints = 
  ListPlot[nonEmptyContours, PlotStyle -> {Black, Green, Orange, Red}];
Show[{sdh, cp, coloredByContourPoints}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This a question for the Graphics folks…is there a way to decide colors based on how “extreme” they seem? The green really seems to stand out here and so I’d want it to be the outermost color. Orange should really be the second color because it doesn’t stand out so much

Comment: Thanks! this works perfectly!