# MultivariateStatistics, Ellipsoids, and other delights

Tags: graphics, probability-or-statistics

Using the slowly-assimilated-by-the-borg `MultivariateStatistics` package, one can compute confidence ellipses using the `EllipsoidQuantile` function. This function returns an `Ellipsoid`, as you'd hope it would, but, it appears that `MultivariateStatistics` goes through the trouble of redefining `Ellipsoid` on its own.

To wit:

[image: ouch]

Then:

[image]

So it gets 'enhanced' (but not **shadowed**) with this fancy new version as supplied by `MultivariateStatistics`. Thats nice, but I sure would like to use the regular old version of `Ellipsoid`. The current version sort of only works ---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(note 1. **red** shadow syntax highlighting for `MultinormalDistribution` and 2. the ellipsoid isn't styled (filled) ala the WL built-in one.) but if I want to change styling of the `Ellipsoid` the down-valued version complains about stuff in the charting package ---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Any ideas of what to do here, best-practice-wise? I can think of a few things involving unprotecting, clobbering, etc, that might work... but was wondering if there was a 'right' way.

Comment: wow. thanks for the edit. I was just pointing out that the package is ½ assimilated by the Wolfram Language, in a lighthearted way. This is why I hate posting here.

Comment: See [`here`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/81128/9362)

Comment: Thanks @BobHanlon ! I swear I looked :)