# Filtering data 'geometrically'

Tags: list-manipulation, regions, filtering

I was looking at a very nice answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/81061/how-to-draw-confidence-ellipse-from-a-covariance-matrix), where the question was applying a confidence region to some data.

If we plot some data as a scatter plot:

```
XData = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1,1], 100000];
YData = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1,1], 100000];

XYDATA = Transpose[{XData, YData}];

XYCoVarMat = Covariance[XYDATA];
XYMean = {Mean[XData], Mean[YData]};


ListPlot[
            XYDATA, Frame->True, FrameLabel->{"X","Y"}, LabelStyle->16, AspectRatio->1,
            Epilog -> {
                            Opacity[0.32, Green], EdgeForm[{Green, AbsoluteThickness[1]}], Ellipsoid[XYMean, 4 XYCoVarMat],
                            Opacity[0.32, Blue], EdgeForm[{Blue, AbsoluteThickness[1]}], Ellipsoid[XYMean, 3 XYCoVarMat],
                            Opacity[0.32, Red], EdgeForm[{Red, AbsoluteThickness[1]}], Ellipsoid[XYMean, 2 XYCoVarMat],
                            Opacity[0.32, Yellow], EdgeForm[{Yellow, AbsoluteThickness[1]}], Ellipsoid[XYMean, 1 XYCoVarMat]
                        },
            PlotRange->{{-8,8},{-8,8}}
        ]
```

I was wondering if anyone knew a way of filtering the data using this approach for example only select data that is with the ellipsoid boundary of 
`Ellipsoid[XYMean, 1 XYCoVarMat]`?

Comment: Would `With[{rmf = RegionMember[Ellipsoid[XYMean, 1 XYCoVarMat]]}, Select[XYDATA, rmf]]` work for you?

Comment: It would work wonderfully. I'm starting to wonder if you are actually written purely from Mathematica functions. Thanks!

Comment: @J.M.willbebacksoon I don't know if you want to post an answer yourself or not, but given you provided the solution I feel you should get credit. If credit doesn't concern you I will accept ThatGravityGuy's answer so that the question is completed and helps users who find this question.

Comment: Please accept ThatGravityGuy's answer if you think you found it useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @J.M. pointed out in the comments, the key here is the function [`RegionMember`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMember.html).  Since you already know the region that you want to work with, namely `Ellipsoid[XYMean, 1 XYCoVarMat]`, you can use [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) as

```
With[{rmf = RegionMember[Ellipsoid[XYMean, 1 XYCoVarMat]]}, Select[XYDATA, rmf]]
```

> {{0.997126,0.575375},{1.67482,1.73},{0.71546,1.72933},<<39325>>,{1.78994,1.09683},{1.23188,0.303475}}

Comment: Thanks for elaborating on my behalf. :)